# select data at different granular level (grouping sets in Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to select data at different granular level (in Oracle). I have a table with data as:

```
c1  c2  c3  c4
a   a1  10  5
a   a2  10  5
b   b1  10  5
b   b2  10  5
```

I need to write a query that would return data as:

```
c1  c2  c3
a   20  10   --aggregated data
a1  10  5    --lowest granular level data
a2  10  5    --lowest granular level data
b   20  10
b1  10  5    -- data of b1, b2 should follow the data of b; likewise a1, a2 should follow data of a
b2  10  5
```

I find this quite unusual because I need to select data at both lowest granular level and an aggregated level. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't see any logic for the new order...

Comment: Have you tried using the CONNECT BY operator in Oracle.
Not sure about the usage but heard it helpful while the result contains hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start from this:

```
SELECT C1, C2, sum(c3), sum(c4), grouping_id(c1, c2)
FROM table_name
group by rollup(c1,c2)
```

To get only your groups you need

```
SELECT C1, C2, sum(c3), sum(c4), grouping_id(c1, c2)
FROM table_name
group by GROUPING SETS ( (c1, c2), c1)
```

see [here](http://www.orafaq.com/node/56) another examples and explanations.

Comment: You got my problem precisely. But I am trying to select c1 or c2 since I need to select c2 for lowest level data and c1 for aggregated data.

Comment: I said that's a start. You can `SELECT nvl(c2, c1), sum(c3), sum(c4)`

Comment: I am having problem to order my data. Using  `order by c1 asc, grouping(c2) desc`   gives data in the order of  `a`  `a2`  `a1`  `b`  `b2`  `b1` . On using `order by c1 asc, grouping(c2) asc` gives data in order of  `a1`  `a2`  `a`  `b1`  `b2`  `b` .But I need in the order `a` `a1` `a2` `b` `b1` `b2`.

Comment: It gives data as `a1` `a2` `a` `b1` `b2` `b`.

Comment: a2 and a1 has same grouping. add column c2: `order by c1 asc, grouping(c2) desc, c2 asc`

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be sure since you're not telling us how you get from one data set to the other.  My guess, though, is that you want something like

```
SELECT c1, sum(c3) c2, sum(c4) c3
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY c1
UNION ALL
SELECT c2, sum(c3), sum(c4)
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY c2;
```

Comment: You got my problem but I need to preserve the order. Since 'a1', 'a2' fall under 'a' category, the data of a1, a2 should succeed the data of 'a' category and the data of b1, b2 should succeed the data of 'b' category and so on.

Comment: @chemicalkt - Are you guaranteed that the data will sort alphabetically the way your sample data does?  If not, how do know whether to return the `a` rows first or the `b` rows first?

Comment: a or b rows can be returned in any order but a1 , a2 should be returned after a and b1 , b2 should be returned after b.